# why a java proccess's resident memory and virtual memory usage is very different between jre 1.6.43 and jre 1.7.25

Tags: java, virtual-memory

When a java proccess run in jre 1.6.43,I use top command to monitor the memory usage,show as fellow:

```
top - 09:14:05 up 13 days, 23:04,  2 users,  load average: 1.78, 1.35, 1.25
Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.5%us,  1.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 95.7%id,  1.5%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:     23651M total,    23466M used,      184M free,      402M buffers
Swap:    40962M total,        0M used,    40962M free,    17427M cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                 
23764 sysomc    20   0  695m 467m  12m S   16  2.0  58:53.41 java
```

Then, I run the java proccess in jre 1.7.25,the top command show the memory usage like:

```
top - 10:40:26 up 15 days, 31 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.77, 0.89, 0.87
Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.5%us,  1.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 95.5%id,  1.6%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:     23651M total,    19892M used,     3758M free,     1651M buffers
Swap:    40962M total,        0M used,    40962M free,    12055M cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                 
27282 sysomc    20   0 1100m 896m  13m S    2  3.8   1:34.51 java
```

The problem is that,why a java proccess's resident memory and virtual memory usage is very different between jre 1.6.43 and jre 1.7.25

Comment: Perhaps a different default initial/max heap size between versions? I don't know for sure. There is a code snippet in the second post at http://www.coderanch.com/t/445962/java/java/Heap-size-JVM that shows you how to print the default and maximum heap size. Try it on both versions and post what you find.

Comment: Supply your own `-Xms` and `-Xmx` options to both JVMs, making sure to give each one the same argument, and see what happens.